Unknown bacterial culture
I had taken a sample of bacteria from my toilet bowl and allowed it to grow on an agar plate. After 3 days, it now has a number of colonies and smells really bad. This was originally for my school science fair(next week) Now I am really scared that the culture may contain pathogenic bacteria. Is it safe to continue the culture or should I dispose it off?? Please help

If you need to show it to someone: clean your hands. Open a clean ziplock bag, place the petrie dish inside of it, and wash your hands again without touching anything else. Then seal the ziplock bag. It will be good for a couple of days this way. If you need more time, use photographs, or repeat the experiment, maintaining good hygiene throughout to avoid contaminating your sample. Don't bring the petrie dish into a public place without adequate isolation of the contents.

The project might benefit greatly if you could identify some of the microorganisms. A quick google search seems to indicate that some ways of identification are accessible to school students. For example this page lists a few methods like selective agar media. Perhaps your school or someone you know has a microscope?

Without the proper tests to identify the bacteria you have no method of identifying which species you have isolated and there is a chance that some of them are pathogens, especially as you have isolated from somewhere that is used for sanitation. There's a goodish chance that you haven't just isolated bacteria, but also yeast and other fungi.
Feces contains quite a range of bacteria, many species of which are opportunistic pathogens such as Escherichia coli (the famous "E. coli"), some strains of which are quite pathogenic. There are also species from genera like Shigella, Salmonella, Klebsiella, Clostridium and many others which are very common pathogens.
Handling these sorts of things is not necessarily dangerous with appropriate training and proper precautions (e.g. gloves, washing and sanitizing hands properly). If you decide to go ahead, make sure that you don't open the plate(s), to ensure that you can't spread the isolates around. If you do not have someone to advise on techniques and train you, you should not handle the samples!
You should discard the plate(s) in a biohazardous waste stream, do not just throw in the rubbish. Your school may be able to help with this.

Thanks for the answer. I have taped the lid of the agar plates and will be using gloves and a mask when handling them. The bacteria, or fungi will not have any effect on anybody if it the lids are not opened, right?

Not necessarily - the plates are designed so that there is airflow between the agar and the outside, so still a chance of liquid coming out. If you could seal them in a container or use clingfilm to seal the edges, that would be better.

Will ziploc bags be sufficient? Sorry for asking too many questions. I want to display the cultures but I also don't want them to harm anyone else.

Yes, Ziplocs would be perfect.

Oops, sorry, I didn't see this comment thread.
